# How to Generate a TextBox in BlankApp using C# (without xaml) During runtime in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tBox = new TextBox();
        tBox.Width = 500;
        tBox.Header = "Notes";
        tBox.PlaceholderText = "Type your notes here";
     }
```

I can create the attributes or properties of the textbox,but how do I generate the design view of textbox in c#. This is not wpf application..

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is not clear, what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to create a text box when i click on a button using c# .

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229019/how-to-dynamically-generate-a-textbox-control

Comment: that is for windows form application and i'm looking for a blank application in visual studio.

Comment: ok, what do you mean by "blank application" Be more specific

Comment: In Visual studio it is specified application targeted towards windows store 8.1 and Windows 10  store...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming this is a Windows Forms app?  If so, check [this out](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319266)...

Comment: its not windows form application

Comment: Is it a windows desktop app written in Managed Code?  If so, your only choices are Windows Forms, WPF, and Xamarin Forms.  Which of these is it?

Comment: it is a windows desktop store app

Comment: Okay, so are you using Xaml to create the forms.  If so, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36662753/dynamically-add-ui-elements-to-stackpanel-after-button-pressed